# Format output with empty columns

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to format the output provided by `qstat` (SGE) into CSV. The provided output has 8 columns. Column number 7 (queue) can be empty, as is seen in the last two lines:

```
job-ID  prior      name user            state submit/start at         queue                                                           slots 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 12345 0.25000 jobA   michael      r        07/17/2018 17:54:49  something@somehostname.com    72        
 12346 0.25000 jobB   michael      r        07/17/2018 17:54:49  something@somehostname.com    72        
 12347 0.25000 jobC   michael      qw    07/17/2018 13:52:12                                                                        72        
 12348 0.25000 jobD   michael      qw    07/17/2018 13:52:20                                                                        72
```

My current approach via `awk` works, but struggles with the empty 7th column.

```
qstat | awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6" "$7","$8","$9}' | sed '2d'
```

This will produce the following output:

```
job-ID,prior,name,user,state,submit/start at,queue,slots
12345,0.25000,jobA,michael,r,07/17/2018 17:54:49,something@somehostname.com,72
12346,0.25000,jobB,michael,r,07/17/2018 17:54:49,something@somehostname.com,72
12347,0.25000,jobC,michael,qw,07/17/2018 13:52:12,72,
12348,0.25000,jobD,michael,qw,07/17/2018 13:52:20,72,
```

The output that I'd like to have is this (notice the empty 7th column in the last two lines and no `,` at the end of these lines):

```
job-ID,prior,name,user,state,submit/start at,queue,slots
12345,0.25000,jobA,michael,r,07/17/2018 17:54:49,something@somehostname.com,72
12346,0.25000,jobB,michael,r,07/17/2018 17:54:49,something@somehostname.com,72
12347,0.25000,jobC,michael,qw,07/17/2018 13:52:12,,72
12348,0.25000,jobD,michael,qw,07/17/2018 13:52:20,,72
```

Comment: what is the delimiter between columns provided by `qstat`? is it tabs or space characters? also, from sample shown, it looks like it is fixed-width format.. in which case you can use FIELDWIDTHS with GNU-awk, or use `cut` if it supports specifying output delimiter and post process to remove leading/trailing whitespace

Comment: It's space delimited. Good point regarding the fixed-width format. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: The input is not fixed width fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' 'NF<9{$9=$8; $8=""} {$1=$1} NR!=2' file
job-ID,prior,name,user,state,submit/start,at,queue,slots
12345,0.25000,jobA,michael,r,07/17/2018,17:54:49,something@somehostname.com,72
12346,0.25000,jobB,michael,r,07/17/2018,17:54:49,something@somehostname.com,72
12347,0.25000,jobC,michael,qw,07/17/2018,13:52:12,,72
12348,0.25000,jobD,michael,qw,07/17/2018,13:52:20,,72
```

or if you really care about the date and time being a single field:

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' 'NF<9{$9=$8; $8=""} NR!=2{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6 " " $7, $8, $9}' file
job-ID,prior,name,user,state,submit/start at,queue,slots
12345,0.25000,jobA,michael,r,07/17/2018 17:54:49,something@somehostname.com,72
12346,0.25000,jobB,michael,r,07/17/2018 17:54:49,something@somehostname.com,72
12347,0.25000,jobC,michael,qw,07/17/2018 13:52:12,,72
12348,0.25000,jobD,michael,qw,07/17/2018 13:52:20,,72
```

Answer (score 1):

if your Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you on same.

```
awk '
FNR==1 && match($0,/.*\/start/){
  sub(/ +$/,"")
  val1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/ +/,",",val1)
  val2=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
  gsub(/ +/,",",val2)
  sub(/[a-zA-Z]+$/,",&",val2)
  print val1,val2
  next
}
match($0,/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/){
  gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")
  val1=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
  gsub(/ +/,",",val1)
  val2=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
  gsub(/ +/,",",val2)
  if($0 !~ /[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.com/){ sub(/[0-9]+$/,",&",val2)}
  print val1 substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) val2
}'   Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to get rid of the tailing `,`, but it does not add the empty column before that.

Comment: @MichaelGecht, ok sure 2 mins will fix it now, do you need it in all lines or only apart from 1st line?

Comment: @MichaelGecht, could you please check now and let me know if this helps you, it enters `,,` for all the lines.

Comment: I only want it in those lines that do not have any value for the 7th column (`something@somehostname.com`). In the example it's lines 3 and 4, but it could be any line. I don't need the double `,,` for those lines with a hostname.

Comment: @MichaelGecht, I will fix it and get back in few mins.

Comment: @MichaelGecht, could you please check my edited code now, it will leave those lines which have hostname in them, let me know then?

Comment: It still gives me the extra `,` in the first two collumns. I've now accepted the other answer because it's fairly short and works as expected. Thanks for your effort!